# C# ASP.NET MVC Passing data to GridView from DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, gridview

I want to do the menu page in a MVC project, there I need to populate some GridViews with different data from some models. First I created some datasets which contain the datatables; in the controller i call the index view which shows the main page.

```
public ActionResult Index()     
    {
        ..........
        return View();
    }
```

Index view

```
 @{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_mainLayout.cshtml"; }

 @{Html.RenderPartial("TicketsPartial");}

 @Html.DevExpress().PageControl(s =>
 {
    s.Name = "tabcontrol";

    s.TabPages.Add(tabPage =>
        { 
            tabPage.Text = "Inbox";

            tabPage.SetContent(() =>
                {

                    Html.RenderPartial("InboxPartial");
                });
        });

    s.TabPages.Add(tabPage =>
    {
        tabPage.Text = "Sent";

        tabPage.SetContent(() =>
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("SentPartial");
        });
    });
}).GetHtml()
```

So I'm trying to use the Html.RenderPartial to call some partial views... here's the code in InboxPartial

```
  @model DataModels.Email.DS_EmailMessages.DT_com_mail_messagesDataTable

  @Html.DevExpress().GridView(s =>
   {
    s.Name = "Inbox";

    s.KeyFieldName = "idticket";

    s.Width = System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Percentage(100);

   }).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

So first I give the model to the view... the datatable from which the data should be loaded and I bind it to the gridview...

The thing is that this isn't displaying any data and also any column...and I really can't understand why... for example if I give the datatabel as a parameter in the controller like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ..........
        return View(dS_Tickets.DT_com_consultant_tickets);
    }
```

And i erase the model from the views so there will not be any conflict, each partialview  will show the columns and data taken from the datatabel, but only from that one table that I gave as a parameter.. I need to take the data from different tables... how can I do this?

Note: I'm using an extension called DevExpress v.12

Comment: if u want data from different tables best method is to use "viewbag"

Comment: Rather Use ViewModel thats more robust coding.